# How to display servlet using liferay 6 and portlet?

Tags: java, servlets, liferay-6, portlet

I am trying to display a servelt. To do that I have a portlet (`.war`) that it deploy inside liferay. I have created privates sites inside liferay to see diferent pages into the porlet (`.xhtml`).
I have defined in `web.xml` a  url to shows servlet content.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>metrics-admin</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>com.codahale.metrics.servlets.AdminServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>/metric/admin/*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>metrics-admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/metrics/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However if I use `postman` and try `GET` I got this:

[image]

I got the pages like "Not Found"

How can I fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was add the follow code only:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>metrics-admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>com.codahale.metrics.servlets.AdminServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

As you can see `metrics-admin` is the servlet name and the way to access it.
The correct URL for this is

`<your-url>.<your-domain>/delegate/<servlet-name>`

and done :D